# Bitnami Django Stack 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: django, postgresql, apache2

I was trying to install Bitnami Django Stack with PostgreSQL but I encountered a problem while just trying out the Demo page. I have been trying to fix it and read the documentation but it seems that the documentation is outdated. When I open the Demo page, it shows the following error:

[image]

Here are the errors found in the log:

```
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:21.679338 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2172] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:21.711930 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2173] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:21.725126 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2173] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 OpenSSL/1.0.2j configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:21.725224 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2173] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:24.877912 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2173] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:27.484248 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2208] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:27.509850 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2209] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:27.519223 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2209] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 OpenSSL/1.0.2j configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:27.519303 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2209] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:29.872885 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2209] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:48.061052 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2267] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:48.085438 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2268] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:48.093839 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2268] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 OpenSSL/1.0.2j configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 19 11:00:48.093925 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2268] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.806807 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=2270): Target WSGI script '/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/django_projects/Demo/Demo/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.806894 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=2270): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/django_projects/Demo/Demo/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.806928 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.806944 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/django_projects/Demo/Demo/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807000 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807012 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807051 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807062 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807097 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807107 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807196 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     app_config.import_models(all_models)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807216 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807277 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807287 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807324 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     __import__(name)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807333 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807428 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807439 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807488 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807498 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807750 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807761 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807778 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807786 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807922 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807932 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807971 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.807980 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808046 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808056 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808071 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808078 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808091 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     __import__(name)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808098 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808171 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808189 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: /bitnami/djangostack-osx-x64/output/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808194 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   Referenced from: /Applications/djangostack-1.10.5-0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
[Sun Feb 19 03:01:55.808198 2017] [:error] [pid 2270] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Can you hit it on port 80?

Comment: It returns "localhost refused to connect" :(

Comment: Which bitnami instance are you using?

Comment: Hmm I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean... I installed the stack here https://bitnami.com/stack/django

Comment: Are you using the virtual machine version or cloud?

Comment: Virtual I suppose. I'm using Mac and I installed the stack under "local install"

Comment: Or is it that besides just doing the local installation, I still need to do something else?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py runserver` after install? It looks like Python isn't running.

Comment: Alright I tried running, new error thrown:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`

Comment: Looks like you missed a couple steps. I added an answer with the link.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to resolve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `python manage.py runserver` after installation. There are a few other post installation things you need to do. You can start at step 3. https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/django/